# Is the plane minus a line segment homeomorphic with punctured plane?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Is $\mathbb R^2$ minus a line segment i.e. $\mathbb R^2 \setminus ([0,1]\times \{0\}) $ homeomorphic with a punctured plane $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ ?

Comment: Using the imagination yes, they are homeomorphic but I dont have a clue about how to prove it formally.

Comment: @Masacroso : I also think they are hoemomorphic with no rigorous way to support my intuition . A similar question is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1831615/is-the-complement-of-the-closed-unit-disk-in-the-plane-homeomorphic-with-mathb

Comment: We need something like change of angle $\to$ translation over $x$ axis. Something related to the bijective deformation of a circle into an ellipse.

Comment: Consider the homeomorphism from $2$-space minus your line to $2$-space minus the $\infty$-norm ball that opens up the line at $1/2$. Now $2$-space minus a point is homeomorphic to $2$-space minus the usual $2$-norm ball, and you can now radially push the $\infty$-norm ball to the usual ball.

Comment: I would be nice to prove this via either (1) some intuitive bit of elementary Euclidean geometry or (2) a holomorphic bijection from $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ to $\mathbb C \setminus (\mathbb R\setminus[0,1])$ whose inverse is holomorphic. (But I don't know how to do either of those.) $\qquad$

Comment: @ Michael Hardy: if it were the case, it seems to me that (by adding the point at infinity and inverting) we could obtain a biholomorphic mapping between $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C} \setminus ([2, +\infty) \cup (-\infty,-2])$, which is impossible.

Comment: @MichaelHardy As I show in my answer, there is no conformal mapping between these spaces, but we can get darn close, conformally mapping the complement of a line segment to the open punctured disk, which is easily shown to be homeomorphic to $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ by a nonconformal map. $f(z)=\cos z$ is also a nice punchline here.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, there are too many minuses in your formula for the second domain.  What you wrote is actually simply connected, so it is not going to be homeomorphic to the complement of a point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The map $(x,y)\mapsto (u,v)$, described below, is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$. Indeed, each of the three pieces is continuous, and they agree on overlaps.
$$v=y,\qquad u=\begin{cases} x,\quad &x\le 0,\\ x/|y|,\quad & 0\le x\le |y|, \\ x-|y|+1,\quad &x>|y|  \end{cases}  $$
Also, the image of any point in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$  is contained in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus([0,1]\times \{0\})$.

The inverse of the aforementioned map is 
$$y=v,\qquad x=\begin{cases} u,\quad &x\le 0,\\ u|v|,\quad & 0\le u\le 1, \\ u+|v|-1,\quad &u>1  \end{cases} $$
It is continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$; again, because the pieces agree on overlaps. The image of any point in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus([0,1]\times \{0\})$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$.

The combination of stated properties implies the map is a desired homeomorphism.

Answer (score 8):

Let $A=\mathbb R^2\setminus([0,1]\times\{0\})$ and $B=\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0,0\}.$ Place a coordinate system on $A$ by labeling each point $(\ell,\theta)$ where $\ell$ is the euclidean distance from the point to the line segment $L=[0,1]\times\{0\}$, and $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ is the angle of the point from some fixed ray in $\mathbb R^2$. Put the standard polar coordinates on $B$. Define $f:A\to B$ by $f(\ell,\theta)=(\ell,\theta)$.

A simple convexity argument is enough to show bijectivity. Continuity in both directions is harder to show rigorously, but not hard to see.

Comment: What is meant by the angle of a point from a ray? Does it mean that $\theta$ can be, for example, the angular co-ordinate in standard polar co-ordinates?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. I didn't want to say polar coordinates here because the coordinate system on $A $ is not polar, but the angle is the same.

Comment: I wonder whether there is a more general topological approach that would be applicable to other similar Q's. For example, if we identify the sphere $S^2$ with $R^2\cup \{p\}$ and we remove either a single point or the segment $[0,1]\times \{0\}$ from $S^2$ then.....?

Answer (score 7):

For convenience, I will work with $\Bbb R^2\setminus([-1,1]\times\{0\})$ instead, which is obviously homeomorphic to your space by an affine transformation. The ellipse with foci at $\pm1$ and sum of distances to the foci equal to $2(r+1)$ has major axis $a=r+1$ and minor axis $b=\sqrt{r(r+2)}$, which yields the parameterization

$$x=(r+1)\cos\theta\\y=\sqrt{r(r+2)}\sin\theta$$

which is a homeomorphism from the $(r,\theta)$ polar parameterization of $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ to the cartesian parameterization of $\Bbb R^2\setminus([-1,1]\times\{0\})$. (I find this parameterization preferable to those of @Soup and @AlexS. because it is not piecewise.)

[image: ellipse parameterization]

---

From the picture, it looks like there is likely to be an underlying conformal map, if the $r$-parameterization is fixed to satisfy Cauchy-Riemann. Setting $r=f(\alpha)$ and equating the $\partial_\alpha$ and $\partial_\theta$ partial derivatives gives $f(\alpha)=2\sinh^2(\alpha/2)=\cosh\alpha-1$ as a conformal $(\alpha,\theta)$ parameterization, and plugging this back in gives the parameterization

$$(x,y)=(\cos\theta\cosh\alpha,\sin\theta\sinh\alpha)$$
                                        [image: conformal map]

which is easily seen to be the conformal map corresponding to $f(z)=\cos z$. In other words, $\cos z$ is a homeomorphism from the quotient of the top half-plane $\{z\in\Bbb C\mid\Im z>0\}$ under the equivalence $z\sim w$ iff $z-w\in 2\pi\Bbb Z$, to $\Bbb C\setminus[-1,1]$; at the same time $f(x+iy)=ye^{ix}$ is a homeomorphism from this space to $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$. Note that the second map is not holomorphic, and indeed there is no such holomorphic map. They are not conformally equivalent because $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is the punctured plane and $\Bbb C\setminus[-1,1]$ is conformally equivalent to the punctured disk $\{z\mid0<|z|<1\}$ via the above $\cos z$ mapping and $e^{-iz}$, and the punctured plane and punctured disk are not conformally equivalent by the Riemann mapping theorem for doubly connected domains.

Answer (score 4):

Without writing formulas this can be seen by noting that the universal cover in both cases is the disk, while the fundamental group in both cases is $\mathbb{Z}$.  Therefore in the class of orientable manifolds, the quotient manifold must be the cylinder; i.e., both of your spaces are homeomorphic to an infinite cylinder.

Comment: This depends on knowing that Z can act in the plane in only one way or something similar, which does not sound at all easier than the statement you want to prove!

Comment: That's actually not a problem, since the plane minus an interval can be seen as a subset of the plane minus a point, so the action of the fundamental group on the universal cover is literally the same. @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez

Answer (score 4):

This map should do:
$$(x,y)\mapsto\begin{cases}(x+\operatorname{sgn}(x)(|y|-1),y),&|x|>1\\(xy,y),&|x|\le1\end{cases}$$
[image: PL homeomorphism]

Comment: I do not know if there is a piecewise linear map that works.

Comment: No, there is not, assuming finitely many pieces. Let $f$ map $\Bbb R^2\setminus 0$ to $\Bbb R^2\setminus[0,1]$. For each affine piece $f_i(x)=Ax+b$, the operator norm $||A||$ is finite; let $\lambda$ be the maximum over all $i$, so that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le\lambda|x-y|$. The image of $f(\{x\mid0<|x|<\epsilon\})$ is bounded and not simply connected, and hence surrounds the missing line segment; in particular its metric diameter is at least $1$, which is a contradiction if $\epsilon<\frac1{2\lambda}$, because the original set has diameter $2\epsilon$.