# Is the complement of the closed unit disk in the plane homeomorphic with $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\} $ ?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Is $\mathbb R^2 \setminus D^2$ , where $D^2=B[0;1]$ is the closed unit disk , homeomorphic with $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\} $  ?

Comment: yes, it is. do you ask for a reason?

Comment: No. Just FYI. Maybe you're automatically  notified, as you posted an A....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the homeomorphism is $x\mapsto x+\frac{x}{\left\|x\right\|}$.

Comment: Another one: In polar co-ordinates $(r,\theta)$. For  $r>1,$  map $(r,\theta)$ to $(r-1,\theta)$.

Comment: @user254665 this is actually the inverse of the exact same homeomorphism :-)

Comment: Your comment is  right. I see that the Q is on hold.

Comment: weird... wondering what preliminaries are missing to these 5 guys.