# Prove that a function between two topological spaces is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functions, continuity

[Is the complement of the closed unit disk in the plane homeomorphic with $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{(0,0)\} $ ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1831615/1274801)

My question is about the above, somebody has defined a function and its fine. But for proving that the function is homeomorphism we need to show that $f(U)$ is open if and only if $U$ is open.($f$ here means that function.)

I do not know how to prove "$f(U)$ is open if and only if $U$ is open".

Thank for your time.

Comment: It is maybe better to find the inverse, and show that it is continuos as well

Comment: If you have already shown it is a bijection, then your work in showing it is a surjection may give you a clue into how to construct an inverse. If you want to show it is a homeomorphism, and you have already shown it is a bijection, it suffices to that any $\epsilon$-ball in $\mathbb R^2-\{0\}$ gets mapped to an open set in $\mathbb R^2-D^2$.

Comment: I got that @Chris, Thanks.

Comment: Also note that in polar coordinates (which are valid in $\mathbb R^2\smallsetminus \{0\}$, your function is given by $(r,\theta)\mapsto (r+1,\theta)$, which has a very easy to define inverse.

Comment: I could find that inverse which is $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y)(1-1/(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}))$, but I still can not show that every open ball will mapped to an open set. @Chris

Comment: If you have the inverse, and it's continuous then you are done

Comment: Is it Ok to proof the continuity of inverse or the main function with metric space tools? I mean using epsilon-delta or equivalently limitation notation. @Chris

Comment: Absolutely, epsilon delta is equivalent to inverse image of every open is open

Comment: great, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer to the linked question says that

$$h : \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{ (0,0) \} \to \mathbb R^2 \setminus D^2, h(x) = x + \frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert} = \frac{\lVert x \rVert + 1}{\lVert x \rVert}x \tag{1}$$

is a homeomorphism. The map $h$ is well-defined since
$$\lVert h(x)\rVert = \frac{\lVert x \rVert + 1}{\lVert x \rVert} \lVert x  \rVert = \lVert x  \rVert +1  > 1 \tag{2}$$
Clearly $h$ is continuous.

Of course one can try to show directly that $h$ is a bijection and an open map, but is more efficient find an inverse for $h$. Looking at $(1)$ suggests that
$$g: \mathbb R^2 \setminus D^2 \to \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{ (0,0) \}, g(y) = \frac{\lVert y \rVert - 1}{\lVert y \rVert}y \tag{3} $$
is the right candidate. The map $g$ is well-defined since $\lVert g(y) \rVert = \frac{\lVert y \rVert - 1}{\lVert y \rVert} \lVert y  \rVert = \lVert y  \rVert - 1  > 0$. Clearly $g$ is continuous.

Using $(2)$ we get
$$g(h(x)) = \frac{\lVert h(x) \rVert - 1}{\lVert h(x) \rVert}h(x) = \frac{\lVert x \rVert}{\lVert x \rVert + 1}\frac{\lVert x \rVert + 1}{\lVert x \rVert}x = x$$
which means $g \circ h = id$. Similarly we get $h \circ g = id$.

This proves that $h$ and $g$ are homeomorphisms which are inverse to each other.